# multiplying an integer by a returned value of a function

Tags: python-3.x

noobie here, sorry for what is probably an inane question but couldn't seem to find an explanation when I searched for it... surprised by by the output of multiple numerals instead of a product when multiplying an integer by the returned value of a function.

```
def number():
    four=input('input the number 4: ')
    return four
x=number()
y=4
print(4*x)
print(4*y)
print(4*4)
```

output...

```
input the number 4: 4
4444
16
16
```

I guess I am not understanding return... I was expecting 16 in the example above, not 4444

Answer (score 0):

The result of:

```
four=input('input the number 4: ')
```

when the user does what you ask, is to place the *string* `'4'` (not the number) into the variable named `four`, as per the type output in the following snippet:

```
>>> x = input('what: ')
what: 4
>>> print(x, type(x))
4 <class 'str'>
```

And, if you evaluate `'4' * 7`, you will indeed get `4444444`, because addition of strings is concatenation, rather than numeric accumulation:

```
>>> print('4' * 7)
4444444
>>> print(4 * 7)
28
```

If you want to turn that string into an integer, try<sup>(a)</sup> something like:

```
four=int(input('input the number 4: '))
```

---

An apt word in this case, since you should probably do it inside a `try..catch` block on the off chance the user doesn't do what you ask :-)

Comment: Thank you... into the rolodex... input returns a string.... numbers that are strings are not integers.... try... catch next on the chopping block,  Thanks again for the help and suggestion!